# View file History in Visual SourceSafe-in VS-2008

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

I am working in Visual studio-2008(VSS). Now i need to get file, which are ChickIn in this month.

For that i want to View History for files.

I tried with [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx257thz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). But according this i am not find the **SourceSafe Options** in **Tools**(options).

Please any one can help me.

Thanks,
Jagadi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check whether you chose Visual SourceSafe as the current SCC Provider on the menu Tools->Options->Source Control.